# ng-click functions not firing inside html select element

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the following html dropdown in an Angular view:

HTML

```
        <select>
          <option value="Func 1">
                <button class="btn ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" ng-click="callFunc1()">
                    <span class="btn-icon add"></span>
                    Func 1
                </button>   
          </option>
          <option value="Func 2">
                <button class="btn ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" ng-click="callFunc2()">
                    <span class="btn-icon add"></span>
                    Func 2
                </button>   
          </option>
        </select>
```

JS

```
        $scope.callFunc1= function() {
            alert('func 1');

        }; 

        $scope.callFunc2 = function() {
            alert('func 2');

        };
```

My problem is the functions attached to the ng-clicks aren't firing.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Please show us your javascript. Are callFunc1() and callFunc2() in scope of angular controller?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to put buttons in options, you could add `ng-change` and `ng-model` to `<select>`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest following something similar to this format.  How you decide to pass around the data is completely up to you, but this should provide some guidance.

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <!--js-->
    <script>
    app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){

        $scope.selectValue = undefined;

        $scope.event = function(){
            console.log($scope.selectValue)
        }
    })
    </script>
    <div>
        <select ng-model="selectValue" ng-change="event()">
        <option value="test">something</option>
        <option value="test2">something2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Make sure all html is within your controller and that you've initiated the body of your html with ng-app (not shown above).  ng-change will fire the expression that you pass it when you make a change to the select input.  Also, ng-change requires that you assign an ng-model value to your element.